# Keypress on Input - Auto Fill Form & Scroll To Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to have an input field at the top of a page that when I fill out and press enter it smooth scrolls to a div at the bottom of the same page and auto completes the corresponding field in the form within that div. I have the keypress working for auto populating the corresponding field in the form, but I can't get it to scroll.

```js
$("#form-stub-name").keypress(function(){
        $("#first-name").val(this.value);
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            $(".form-stub-button").click();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#schedule').offset().top -155}, 950);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="form-stub-name" id="form-stub-name" type="text">
    <div id="schedule">
     <form>
      <input name="first-name" id="first-name" value="" type="text">
     </form>
    </div>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I have actually found this works in Chrome, but not Firefox or Edge.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts on this at all? Again, Chrome is good, it just appears to be Firefox and Edge that have an issue with this.